# Как правильно создать второй сайдбар?

Tags: php, wordpress

Я создаю новый файл, допустим «sidebar-top». Делаю его динамическим

```
<?php if ( function_exists ( dynamic_sidebar(2) ) ) : ?>
```

Далее захожу в функцию, и регистрирую его

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name'=>'sidebar-top',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="site-description">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>'
```

));

Далее я вызываю этот сайдбар в нужно мне месте?

Answer (score 0):

Еще нужен `id` у сайдбара чтобы его вызывать `dynamic_sidebar('st')`, в моем случае `id = st`

```js
register_sidebar( array(
  'name'          => 'sidebar-top',
  'id'            => "st",
  'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
  'after_widget'  => "</li>\n",
 ) );
```